What part of a subjunctive sentence is actually in the subjunctive?
In my studies of French I noticed the subjunctive mood is talked about almost exclusively in the context of dependent clauses which take the form of "que/qui + verb in the subjunctive". It makes me wonder whether in English hypotheticals in a main clause and verbs not marked by modal verbs are actually in the subjunctive. I have read relevant Wikipedia pages and consulted several other sources online but I am still not quite clear on this. So for example


If he were here right now he would help.
If I were to talk about the event I would start with the preparation.
If only I had more money.
Would that it were so simple.


Which of these verbs are in the subjunctive? I've always thought they are all in the subjunctive but they do seem to have different syntactic roles and patterns, and are treated differently (a realization I only came to while studying French).

I would say 1 and 4 are definitely in the subjunctive.

@user405662 Well, all of the sentences are, but that's not the question. I am talking about the syntactic nitty-gritty: verbs and verb forms, not on a sentential level.

I think you are looking at it the wrong way: a limited number of different constructions require (or can take) the subjunctive. (#1 and #2 need commas. )

@DjinTonic No. Use of commas is stylistic and has nothing to do with syntax and it's beside the question. Also, nope to the second comment as well.

@DjinTonic I'd treat commas as optional there.

Each of these displays a verb usage triggered by the subjunctive mood.

None of them are. The subjunctive mood was lost in earlier stages of the language. Today, mood is mostly marked in English by modal auxiliaries. The ill-named 'past subjunctive' is best called 'irrealis were', an untidy relic of an earlier system. Some speakers usually, if not always, use preterite "was" instead.

The three occurrences of "were" are cases of the were-subjunctive. The occurrence of "had" has to do with hypothetical fact also, and does not represent a true use of the past in that sentence, but it is not considered to be a subjunctive verb form. This tense is called the hypothetical past (§ 4.16). Incidentally, as you are trying to draw similarities with French, this is a construction in which French does not use a subjunctive but a tense of the past in the indicative mood (the "imparfait"), and it is not a true indicative either. There is, then,  a striking similarity between these two  grammatical contexts.

"If only I had money…" translates to "Si seulement j'avais de l'argent…".

In the words of Quirk et al. (A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, 1985, § 3.62), the were-subjunctive may be regarded as a fossilized inflection: it is nowadays a less usual alternative to the hypothetical past indicative. In addition, they contend that  "examples of hypothetical were with a 2nd person or plural subject (eg: you were . . ., they were . . .) are therefore to be viewed as indicative, rather than as a neutralization of indicative and subjunctive".
Addition
"Be to" is a modal idiom, that is, not a central modal, as can, may, etc., this being so, among other things, because of the possibility of using  an -s form. In conditional clauses were to is a subjunctive and it expresses hypothetical future meaning.  (CoGEL § 3.45-46)

So 2 is in the subjunctive?

@user405662 Yes, it is; I made an addition to my answer.
